# Tracking down where favicon is being linked

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I have a website I'm working on and it appears the old developer wrote some code somewhere to hardcode in a favicon. It's causing the `mixed content warning` with my SSL. Is there any simple way of tracking down where this is hardcoded in?  I deleted the favicon files, and the default favicon was then set, but I still got the warning. That's why I think it's hardcoded in somewhere. I even tried deleting the files, but still get the warning (so I added them back in for now.)

In chrome inspector it just says

```
Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page "http://*****.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/faviconanciecor32x32-darkenboxblue.jpg"[Learn More]
```

Normally I have an idea of where it's located by the text after that, but this time it's just saying `ContentLinkHandler.jsm`

Found this in the header file

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/favicon.ico' ?>" />
```

Which is clearlyfor the favicon set via the theme settings. It's empty right now so when I delete the images to the link shown above, the default favicon for the theme settings appears. So somewhere in the code the darkenbluebox line is overriding the code in the header file.

Comment: Maybe in header file, or WordPress is thinking that, that is right. Have you updated path, in WordPress settings?

Comment: I've checked Header, Footer, Index, etc. Can't seem to find it. My path in Wordpress settings is correct yes. Everything else works fine besides that link that I can't find where it's being called from, that's why I believe it's hardcoded in. I also found this (see edit) in the header which sets the favicon to the one set in the Theme settings (which is empty right now - so the default one shows up ONLY when I delete the icons shown in the path above). This also leads me to believe that wherever the override is happening it's overriding that in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are loading parts using HTTP instead of HTTPS. Of course in this case it's the favicon, but it may be some other resources as well, including scripts and images from other sources.

Since you are using WordPress, I would suggest installing the HTTPS plug-in:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/

It will take care of all those SSL errors. If its default settings are not enough, select the one that says "Remove elements inaccessible over HTTPS", which in turn will disable your favicon.

Good luck,